# Visual Studio c# 2013 - Indent all documents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have taken over a c# solution - vs2013, all the source files are not indented properly, there are like more than 500 pages to be indented.
Would like to know if there is a better solution to format the documents other than opening each document to format.

- Is there any function in VS / 3rd party plugin or programs that can achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [CodeMaid](http://www.codemaid.net/) for this, it does exactly what you want. It's a free extension for Visual Studio. If you want to do indenting manually, you could use the shortcut CTRL K + CTRL D.